# differentiate between user drag and animateCamera on google maps in flutter

Tags: google-maps, flutter, user-interface

In Flutter and using the google_maps_flutter library (v0.5.28), I'm trying to find a way to capture a user drag/pan and differentiate it from calling animateCamera(...) on the map's controller. Either method equally triggers the map's onCameraMove event.

I've tried layering a GestureDetector over top of it, but the drag/pan won't pass through. **edit - what I really mean is wrapping the map in one, not actually putting one over it in a stack. Sorry.

I've tried adding custom gesture detectors to the map's gestureDetectors collection, but they don't seem to fire when I specifically wire up the onUpdate event to the PanGestureDetector I put in that collection.

Various iterations and customizations to the above.

So, I'm presenting this question with the listed qualifications:
How do I capture a user's panning the google maps widget, separating the resulting event so I can easily determine that it's a user pan versus camera animation, or even handle it completely independently?

Ultimately, I just want to capture the user drag, use that to call a setState(...) on boolean flag that I'm using elsewhere.

I fully recognize I've probably overlooked something obvious in all my rat-holing.

Thanks!